# I want to match this HTML tag using Regex

Tags: html, regex

I want to match this HTML tag using Regex and get the inner text for `<ul>` tag

```
<ul class="test">

<li>Data</li>
<li>Data</li>
<li>Data</li>

</ul>
```

given that `<ul class="test">` is fixed ,, I want to match the inner data of this tag

Comment: you should not match tags with regexes, you should use a HTML parser for this.

Comment: and what language are you using?

Comment: And how do you want to consider nested tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/632133

Comment: @MohamedKamal Please reconsider using regular expressions to parse HTML. There are probably other, less painful, less error-prone, and more efficient methods to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this if you're sure you won't have ul tag inside your ul tag:

```
/<ul class="test">(.*?)<\/ul>/
```

If, however, you do have nested tags, well, it'd depends on what language you're using. Eg, in PHP:

```
/<ul.*?>((?:(?R)|.)*?)<\/ul>/
```